# Restore data database from ibd file not working

Tags: mysql, innodb

**Mysql 5.5** InnoDB is broken. I have only folder mysql with .frm and ibd file.

I found the answer at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/71596/restoring-mysql-tables-from-ibd-frm-and-mysqllogbin-files. After I upgrade Mysql 5.6 and use tutorial at http://www.chriscalender.com/tag/innodb-error-tablespace-id-in-file/ with **Method #2** but any data on table **wp_posts in database wordpress** is not correct. It break mysql (lost connection) when I **ALTER TABLE wp_posts IMPORT TABLESPACE**. I cannot restore it. Please help me.

That is data one record after I fix (data being cluttered between columns):

```
************************* 1. row *************************
                   ID: 2
          post_author: 1
            post_date: 0000-00-09 05:24:20
        post_date_gmt: 9272-08-30 08:00:00
         post_content: V??<<iframe style="width: 100%;" src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe1mpUtq1EYSoLzsVJL_gAv8KCR023wO7uyxU0Tgps1UhHjjg/viewform?embedded=true" width="700" height="1000" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">Đang tải...</i
           post_title: frame>Đăng ký tư
         post_excerpt: 
          post_status:  vấnp
       comment_status: ublish
          ping_status: clos
        post_password: 
            post_name: edopendang-ki-
              to_ping: 
               pinged: 
        post_modified: 0909-02-09 08:38:31
    post_modified_gmt: 1378-05-31 30:54:42
post_content_filtered: 
          post_parent: 1922960506717475414
                 guid: ???        http://duhocvaxuatkhau.co
           menu_order: -315670672
            post_type: age_
       post_mime_type: 
        comment_count: -1629109878096134144
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What's in mysqld.err?

Comment: @RickJames I have only folder mysql folder. It don't have file mysqld.err. Before, I view mysql error log, message is "InnoDB is crash", cannot start mysql.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE:**
Suggest to read this article first.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/288860/restoring-mysql-data-from-ibd-file/288861#288861

I had same issue today and after a few times investigation finally figured it out that before calling the `IMPORT TABLESPACE` it is so important to change the ownership of new files to the `mysql:mysql`.

So:

No.1-

```sql
ALTER TABLE my_table DISCARD TABLESPACE;
```

No.2-

```sh
CP /var/lib/mysql/old_db/my_table.ibd /var/lib/mysql/new_db/my_table.ibd
```

No.3-

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql/new_db/my_table.ibd
```

No.4-

```
ALTER TABLE my_table IMPORT TABLESPACE;
```

it works for me and I am super happy :)